# Why clamping voltage is not given for some ESD diodes

Tags: diodes, esd, tvs, surge-protection, diode-clamp

I was comaparing two ESD diodes.Their P/N's are [PESD5V0S1BL,315](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD5V0S1BA_BB_BL.pdf) and

[PESD5V0U1BL,315](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PESD5V0U1BA_BB_BL.pdf).

If you check the datasheet of both parts you can see that clamping voltage is specified for PESD5V0S1BL,315 and they did not mention any clamping voltage for PESD5V0U1BL,315.

[image]
[image]

May I know why it is like that.

Comment: The numbers are right there in the data sheet part where they should be. Why they should be in under the marketing features section?

Comment: What you're after is mostly the reverse standoff voltage anyways, and the reverse breakdown voltage is also listed. The reverse clamping voltage varies significantly with the current being conducted so the value that's given is actually not as useful as you might think.

Comment: I am not able to see the camping voltage spec of PESD5V0U1BL,315 in it's datasheet

Comment: @Justme Right where? I see a V_CL defined in Fig.3 but no parameter given. And we can assume Fig.4 is typical, not guaranteed maximum. Hari: good eye, the datasheet indeed seems to be lacking this datum. The only party who can answer your question, however, is the manufacturer themselves: https://www.nxp.com/support/support:SUPPORTHOME

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PESD5V0U1BA_BB_BL

> V(BR) breakdown voltage IR = 5 mA 5.5 7 9.5 V

PESD5V0S1BA_BB_BL

> V(BR) breakdown voltage IR = 1 mA 5.5 - 9.5 V

Once you have those, you can use the differential resistance to estimate the clamping voltage for different currents. The main difference S1BA 50 ohms vs U1BA 100 ohms.

Comment: Thank you very much.If you don't mind could you please explain this with an example."you can use the differential resistance to estimate the clamping voltage for different currents"